# Ackermann Function Understanding

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm finding it difficult to understand how the Ackermann Function works. I think my understanding of recursion is flawed?

Here is the code in Python:

```
  def naive_ackermann(m, n):
    global calls
    calls += 1
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif n == 0:
        return naive_ackermann(m - 1, 1)
    else:
        return naive_ackermann(m - 1, naive_ackermann(m, n - 1))
```

If I do the function call of naive_ackermann(3,4), how and why do I end up getting 125?

Comments will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What should be output on Paper??

Comment: according to wikipedia 125 is the right answer...

Comment: I don't understand how the function works.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you don't understand and what result you expect.

Comment: I don't understand how from recursively calling the function, you get an output and not a "Maximum Depth Error". How does repeatedly calling this function, produce an output?

Comment: Here is a very good description what it is, what it is for and its place in computability theory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: @S'Koder'Karwa. The best way to understand is to take a paper and pencil.. Take two values suppose (2, 3).. And follow the steps of the algorithm. You will come to know how that ends..

Comment: In any recursive algorithm.. you have a `base condition` which is ultimately reached.. From where, your recursion stops, and you start coming backwards, gradually to the place where you started and with a result..

Comment: @S'Koder'Karwa, notice that in subsequent iterations the value of `m` keeps going down until it reaches 0, when the result is 1+whatever the value of `n` is. That's how one gets an output by repeatedly calling the function.

Comment: Take a look here too, although with `A(3,4)` you'd have to sit for quite a long while for the animation: http://www.gfredericks.com/sandbox/arith/ackermann

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The computation of **A(3,4)** is not as easy or short as it might appear at first from the small values of the arguments. The complexity (# of iteration steps) of the Ackermann function grows very rapidly with its arguments, as does the computed result.

Here is the definition of the Ackermann function from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function):

[image]

As you can see, at every iteration, the value of **m** decreases until it reaches **0** in what will be the last step, at which point the final value of **n** (+1) gives you the answer. So for the answer, you only need to trace how **n** changes as you go through the recursive iterations. For why the Ackermann function grows so rapidly, you can take a look at [**this**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Expansion) subsection of the wiki.

As Joran Beasley has already mentioned, **A(3,4)** is indeed 125, as written in Wikipedia. However, the process to get to this result is not very short. In fact, as I found out, it is required to compute by recursion **315** Ackermann function values to get *A(3,4)*, the number of iterations required being roughly proportional to that.

If you still wish to visualize how this result is arrived at, you can take a look at [**this page**](http://www.gfredericks.com/sandbox/arith/ackermann), which animates the calculation of every recursion step. Be warned, though, that *A(3,4)* will take forever to finish animating here, but at least you might get some idea of the process with smaller arguments.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a version that prints an explanation:

```
def A(m, n, s="%s"):
    print s % ("A(%d,%d)" % (m, n))
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    if n == 0:
        return A(m - 1, 1, s)
    n2 = A(m, n - 1, s % ("A(%d,%%s)" % (m - 1)))
    return A(m - 1, n2, s)

print A(2,2)
```

With arguments 2,2 the output is this. (With 3,4 it becomes already a bit too much)

```
A(2,2)
A(1,A(2,1))
A(1,A(1,A(2,0)))
A(1,A(1,A(1,1)))
A(1,A(1,A(0,A(1,0))))
A(1,A(1,A(0,A(0,1))))
A(1,A(1,A(0,2)))
A(1,A(1,3))
A(1,A(0,A(1,2)))
A(1,A(0,A(0,A(1,1))))
A(1,A(0,A(0,A(0,A(1,0)))))
A(1,A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,1)))))
A(1,A(0,A(0,A(0,2))))
A(1,A(0,A(0,3)))
A(1,A(0,4))
A(1,5)
A(0,A(1,4))
A(0,A(0,A(1,3)))
A(0,A(0,A(0,A(1,2))))
A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,A(1,1)))))
A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,A(1,0))))))
A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,1))))))
A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,2)))))
A(0,A(0,A(0,A(0,3))))
A(0,A(0,A(0,4)))
A(0,A(0,5))
A(0,6)
7
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ackerman(3,4) 

=ackerman(2,ackerman(3,3)) = ackerman(2,61)    #ackerman(3,3) = 61 ...
=ackerman(1,ackerman(2,60)) = ackerman (1,123)  #ackerman(2,60) = 123...
=ackerman(0,ackerman(1,122)) = ackerman (0,124)  #ackerman(1,122) = 124...
= 124+1 = 125
```

see http://goo.gl/jDDEA  here to visualize `ackerman(2,3)`  ( It was too long to visualize 3,4)

Comment: How do you get ackerman(2,61) from ackerman(2,ackerman(3,3))? Where did the 61 come from?

Comment: `ackerman(3,3) = 61` so `ackerman(2,ackerman(3,3)) = ackerman(2,61)`  @MaksymPolshcha how is it wrong ... I looked at that wikipedia entry and all my numbers add up...

Comment: why -1? who put that? please explain

Answer (score 0):

```
def ackermann(m,n):
    """computes the value of the Ackermann function for the input integers m and n.
       the Ackermann function being:
       A(m,n)=n+1               if m=0
             =A(m-1,1)          if m>0 and n=1
             =A(m-1,A(m,n-1)    if m>0 and n>0"""
    if m==0:
        print (n+1)
        return n+1
    elif m>0 and n==0:
        print ("ackermann(",m-1,",",1,")")                                          #just 2 chk intrmdt val. and no. of steps invlvd.can be dltd if necessary
        return ackermann(m-1,1)
    elif m>0 and n>0:
        print ("Ackermann(",m-1,",","Ackermann(",m,",",n-1,")",")")                  #just 2 chk intrmdt val. and no. of steps invlvd.can be dltd if necessary
        return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))
```

Just make a simple modification to your code so that the program prints every steps rather than just the result. The code should look somewhat like what's at the end of this page. Run it, (might take a few seconds) and then you can appreciate how an Ackermann function is computed.

Comment: Please link to the "this page" you mentioned.